# Text in put in CKEDITOR wrap in <p> tag not show on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drupal-7

I build a website using Drupal 7 and in the Body Field, I used "p" tag to wrap around text to display on site.

The website work great on Firefox, Chrome and Safari

But on internet Explorer, the text is not show up 
The weird thing is when I wrap the text using "ol" and "li" tag, the text show :(

I can't post the image yet since I don't have enough reputation but here is the link

http://www.digaraid.com/toyotarichsit/news

The 1st Article was wrap text in "ol" and "li" tag and it show just fine on IE
but

The 2nd Article the text not show because is wrap in "p" tag

I don't know why could you please help

Thank you

Comment: Please paste your code as well, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Thank you bah :) It turn out that the Font I received from Client not support English character. Now when I upload a new font everything is working again. Sorry about the question :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the question, after I dig deeper, I found out that the Webfont that I download has a problem to display Thai language. I upload new web font and everything work fine now :)